# CrystalReportsViewer - Fire Event after parameters loaded/confirm button clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I am working with the CrystalReportsViewer control in a C# desktop application. I want an event to fire when the user finishes entering parameters and the report displays with data. Is there an event I can use for this?

None of the below events do what I am looking for.

```
private void LoadCrystalReportViewer()
{
        crystalReportViewer1.Validated += CrystaLReportViewer1Validated;
        crystalReportViewer1.Load += CrystalReportViewer1OnLoad;
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportRefresh += CrystalReportViewer1OnReportRefresh;
        crystalReportViewer1.BindingContextChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnBindingContextChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.GotFocus += CrystalReportViewer1OnGotFocus;
        crystalReportViewer1.SelectionChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnSelectionChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.Validating += CrystalReportViewer1OnValidating;
        crystalReportViewer1.ViewChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnViewChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.ControlAdded += CrystalReportViewer1OnControlAdded;
        crystalReportViewer1.EnabledChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnEnabledChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.HandleCreated += CrystalReportViewer1OnHandleCreated;
        crystalReportViewer1.StyleChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnStyleChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.SizeChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnSizeChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.VisibleChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnVisibleChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.AutoValidateChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnAutoValidateChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.BackgroundImageChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnBackgroundImageChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.BackgroundImageLayoutChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnBackgroundImageLayoutChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.CausesValidationChanged += CrystalReportViewer1OnCausesValidationChanged;
        crystalReportViewer1.ChangeUICues += CrystalReportViewer1OnChangeUiCues;
}
```

Still haven't found a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this isn't possible. I spoke with someone on SAP about my problem and there is no real solution to my specific problem. If someone wants, I can provide a link to my SAP request.